# MySQL REGEXP format to match year range with slashes in a text field (ie: 1990/93, 1969/70, 1975/2008, etc…)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to devise a MySQL regex that would match—or not match—against dates entered in text fields like this:

```
1990/93
1988/93
1969/70
1990/1996
1984/2007
1975/2008
1973/2011
2003/10
```

The goal is to match a text field—which contains freeform, human entered dates—based on where the date formats seen above show up. The only pitiful thing I have gotten to work is a simple regex that checks for the slash like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `some_objects`
WHERE `date_text` REGEXP '[\/]'
;
```

Which is fairly useless to me since that would just be the equivalent of `LIKE '%/%'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `some_objects`
WHERE `date_text` LIKE '%/%'
;
```

And I am not liking `LIKE` since it just grabs any record that has a `date_text` field that has a slash in it.

What I am looking for is something more robust that works like this:

- If you find a 2-4 digit number.
- And number is followed by a `/`.
- And that `/` is followed by another 2-4 digit number.

Then success!

FWIW, I have been able to code some regex in PHP which works well using lookarounds. So I am posting it as an example. I understand MySQL regex functionality is not as robust as in PHP, but is there some way for me to implement the same—or as close as possible—regex logic in MySQL as I am doing in this PHP script?

```
// Test string including items that should not be matched.
$string = <<<EOT
1990/93
1988/93
1969/70
1990/1996
1984/2007
1975/2008
1973/2011
2003/10
2003/10
not/this
not/10this
/10never
EOT;

// One test.
$regex_pattern = '/[0-9]{4}(?:\/)[0-9]{2,4}/is';

// Another test.
$regex_pattern = '/(?<=[0-9]{4})\/(?=[0-9]{2,4})/is';

// Run it through 'preg_match_all'.
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);

// Echo the results.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output of that would be this. Which is fine. I do not need values. But I do want to match items with that patten in MySQL for retrieval of other fields.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /
            [1] => /
            [2] => /
            [3] => /
            [4] => /
            [5] => /
            [6] => /
            [7] => /
            [8] => /
        )

)
```

Comment: According to the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), there's no reason why what you did in the (first) php example shouldn't work in your query, though it doesn't quite line up with what you said you wanted it to match: `SELECT *
FROM some_objects
WHERE date_text REGEXP "[0-9]{2,4}/[0-9]{2,4}"`

Comment: Why not transform the input data into a more useful form before inserting into DB?

Comment: Actually this would be better: `.. REGEXP "[0-9]{2,4}(/[0-9]{2,4})?"`

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question. I thought I read "And **if**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) may tell you what you want to know:

In this case, the expression would be something like

```
[0-9]{2,4}/[0-9]{2,4}
```

Comment: That's got to be today's high score for Len(question)/Len(answer) :) +1